# Should a WebDAV server support query strings?

Tags: webdav

Should a WebDAV server support query strings?
I have not found a clear statement about this in RFC 4918.

Background is as follows:
I have a WebDAV server where the path in the URL is mapped quasi 1:1 to the path to the resource in the file system. I.e. to get to the resource I need to know the path, something like this:

```
Variant 1:
http://<webdavserver>:<port>/folder1/subfolder1/anotherfolder/resource.txt
```

Now I have another client that doesn't know the path, but only two Ids (RepositoryId and DocumentId), but these also uniquely identify the resource. By searching for the two ids, the WebDAV server can also find the resource and return it.
Until now, this was solved in such a way that instead of the path in the URL, the two IDs were specified as a query string, i.e. something like this:

```
Variant 2:
http://<webdavserver>:<port>/?repoId=123&docId=456
```

Somehow this feels wrong ...

Well, actually the identifcation via the two ids is just an alternative representation to the path, isn't it? So something like this should work too:

```
Variant 3:
http://<webdavserver>:<port>/<repoId>/<docId>
http://<webdavserver>:<port>/123/456
```

This feels more "WebDAV-like" ...

I would only need to be able to distinguish on the server side which of the two URL representations is arriving there, path or ID.
Possibly via a header, something like
`X-ResourcePath: Path | Id` (Default would be Path)

What do you think?
Should I stay with variant 2, or rather switch to variant 3, or ...? (I have to reimplement it anyway, so "Do not change a running system" would not be a valid argument :-))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO: it really doesn't matter. There's no prohibition to mix query params into WebDAV URI trees. You just need to make sure that the clients that you support will work with this.

(I would advise against moving identifying data into custom request header fields; this is what the URI is for).

Answer (score 0):

When I implemented a WebDAV server I was primarily interested in supporting existing clients and I found that most of them did not support query strings in any way (namely Microsoft Office)

I ended up using the following format which seems to work for all clients:

```
protocol://server/id/title.extension
```